# Replace all the matching query parameter value in the URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below Path/URL

```
test = "/test/test-products/?pId=9401100&imgId=14607518&catID=5449&modelId=pros&cm_sp=XIT_resp-_-PR-_-14607518_9401100&lid=xit-test-14607518-9401100";

newPath = test.replace('14607518', '12345678');
```

Not updating every occurrences of the matching string though it has hypen,underscore(-_-)

How can I replace all occurrences of 14607518 with `regex`?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit different since you're using regex here.

```
test.replace(/14607518/g, '12345678');
```

Instead of

```
test.replace('14607518', '12345678');
```

Where the 'g' at the end means 'global', or replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a string instead of regex object to replace it just replaces the first occurrence only, You need to use a `g` tag and regex pattern to replace all the instances

```js
const test = "/test/test-products/?pId=9401100&imgId=14607518&catID=5449&modelId=pros&cm_sp=XIT_resp-_-PR-_-14607518_9401100&lid=xit-test-14607518-9401100";

const newPath = test.replace(/14607518/g, '12345678');

console.log(newPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
([^\d])(14607518)([^\d])
```

because it will help you to avoid accidentally targeting numbers such as `146075189`

```
const regex = /([^\d])(14607518)([^\d])/gm;
const str = `/test/test-products/?pId=9401100&imgId=146075189&catID=5449&modelId=pros&cm_sp=XIT_resp-_-PR-_-14607518_9401100&lid=xit-test-14607518-9401100`;
const subst = `$112345678$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
```

See https://regex101.com/r/0pJWwo/1